# RedHat Developer Studio losing status of JBoss on server restarts

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-developer-studio

I have Developer Studio set up with an instance of JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA. I added it using the 6.1+ server type:

[image]

When I start and stop the server - either in debug mode or not - things seem to work fine. When the server is running and I try to restart it by clicking on the debug button or the play button for non-debug mode, Developer Studio restarts the server (I can see this happening in the logs) but loses track of the server and gives me an error saying:

[image]

After this, the server is running but Dev Studio doesn't know so if I try to start the server, I get this dialog:

[image]

If I then connect, the UI doesn't seem to update so I can't shut down the server:

[image]

This never happens when starting the server from scratch. It's only restarts. I was having this issue with JBoss Developer Studio (Eclipse) with 10.1.0 GA and am now also having the issue with 10.2.0 GA. Is there anything I can tweak to fix this?? Is there a startup or restart timeout that needs to be changed?

Comment: Hi - do you see anything in the console window or in jboss server log file when this happens?

Comment: Nothing that looks like the server has stopped responding but there's a lot of stuff in the logs. I'll try to take a closer look.

Comment: @Chris This seems to be an issue in eclipse server adapter for JBoss EAP 6.1+. I have no tweaks for you to fix it, but I created a JIRA issue for you here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-23887.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed recently :D   It was a long-standing bug and had a race-condition in it.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-20426